# Uploading documents no longer works on public site however works locally?

Tags: php, laravel, iis

I mainly work in C# but had inherited a php / laravel application that works pretty well.  It has been working for quite some time and I have never experienced this issue.  Today around 11AM our site no longer uploads images / standard documents.

We are running on a windows environment with IIS and PHP installed.  We have code that allows you to upload say an image and store some additional information.  PHP / Laravel (Even checked the IIS logs, event viewer, and the laravel logs) and no error happens.  Our application just sits there trying to upload a file.  Eventually our screen just refreshes and the document or file is not uploaded.  If I try this same test locally on my machine (since we developed it) it works fine and the upload happens.

I am aware that permissions on the file location need to be ensured but like I said this works fine for the past year and a half.  Since the site is anon access we use the IUSR account and correct permissions are given to this user for the directories involved (the directories where we store the image documents or files).  I also made sure no windows updates have caused this issue, however the last windows update was on 1/24 and our site was working fine that day up until the 28th of this month.

Code for example looks like this:

```
   // Audit Documents: Label Image
    if ($request->hasFile('audit_label_image')) {
        $document = new Document();
        $document->title = 'Document for Audit with id ' . $audit->audit_id;
        $document->filetype = $request->audit_label_image->extension();
        $document->save();

        $audit_document = new AuditDocument();
        $audit_document->audit_id = $audit->audit_id;
        $audit_document->document_id = $document->document_id;
        $audit_document->type_id = 63; // "Label Image" document type
        $audit_document->save();

        $request->audit_label_image->storeAs('audit', $document->document_id . '.' . $request->audit_label_image->extension() );
    }
```

Our application has a main record that is saved (the audit) and then it goes to save other objects related to an audit.  That is a document and then we store a reference of that Audit to the Document (hence the object above `AuditDocument`).  When we click our "Save" button on our UI it sits there spinning the wheel like it is trying to save the image / document.  No console errors or network errors...it finally refreshes the screen only to have saved the actual "Audit" object in our audit table (sql server), however the document, the audit document, and the image (physicaly file) are not saved.  I even tried writing a small test just to upload a file and we get nothing.

I don't know if its getting a HTTP 500 error (as no errors are given to us).  As mentioned this all stopped working recently but we have not made code changes to cause this.  Not sure where else I can look or any pointers on the php / laravel side that would help me out?

### Update

Any of our forms that have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` are causing this issue.  The minute we remove this line everything works but of course the file does not post.  Is anyone else running on IIS with PHP / Laravel that has ran into this issue in the past?  We have given rights to IUSR, IIS_USERS, IIS_WPG, NETWORK, SYSTEM, AUTHENTICATED USERS, so permissions wise we should be ok...

Comment: Did you check the php version after windows update, also did you debug what happens during the ajax upload in Network (browser console)

Comment: The windows update did not cause this as I mentioned the update came in 1/24 the site has been working through that up till today the 28th.

Comment: @droiddev i have the network tab open and console and nothing comes up.

Comment: Yes I understand that your windows got updated two days before but sometimes it may works from the server cache, once the cache updated the code tends to cause error. I think your ajax file for upload should called. If nothing means there is a problem in java-script while calling the ajax. Check that

Comment: According to your description, we still couldn't find the reason about why the file doesn't save at the server. I suggest you could try to enable the fail request tracing to capture some tracing logs. Then you could analysis the logs to find the details error message. More details about how to use it, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshoot-with-failed-request-tracing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Resolved - Strange one I had to go into `C:\Windows\Temp` and clear that directory, it had 80 gigs worth of temporary files that PHP had generated and never deleted.  The minute I cleared it everything started working.  Whats odd is the server this was on still had plenty of space (over 20 gigs) so I don't know if there was some limitation on this folder?

In any event I am good now!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use Xdebug and look behind the scenes what happens exactly.
here is a laracast link that will help you to how to use it also how to configure with laravel. believe me that will boost your productivity.

[How to use and Configure Xdebug](https://laracasts.com/series/how-to-be-awesome-in-phpstorm/episodes/20)

Comment: This doesnt help I can debug locally it works locally.

Comment: Friend, then you have to debug remotely. same thing.

Answer (score -1):

Enable Logs And see debug it properly, It maybe because the filename is not unique or mime type, low storage on hosting, just debug it using logs